# jquery .add() is weird

Tags: jquery

Why all elements turn red? I only intend to turn `<p>` red.

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
<p>a paragraph</p>

<script>
$('li').add('p').css('background-color', 'red');
</script>
```

Comment: you want to add <p> into the list and change that color into red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('li')` is selection all the li
`$('li').add('p')` is **adding** p tag **into** selected all the `li`
`$('li').add('p').css('background-color', 'red')` is changing `all the li and p` backgroundColor to red.

from [jQuery.add API](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .add()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object
>   from the union of those elements and
>   the ones passed into the method. The
>   argument to .add() can be pretty much
>   anything that $() accepts, including a
>   jQuery selector expression, references
>   to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

Comment: .add doesn't add elements to the dom believe it or not, .add actually just adds elements to the array of selected dom items. so this actually says give me all the li's, add all the p's, and then make them red in the background

Answer (score 2):

jQuery chains events, what you have said here is For each li add a p and make it red.

```
$('li').add('p');
$('li p').css(''background-color', 'red');
```

Should work =0)

Comment: .add doesn't add elements to the dom believe it or not, .add actually just adds elements to the array of selected dom items.  so this actually says give me all the li's, add all the p's, and then make them red in the background.

Answer (score 1):

this actually says give me all the li's, add all the p's, and then make them red in the background. if you just want the p tag to be red, do this:

```
('p').css('background-color', 'red');
```